# How to take account in rotation of pixels in building trajectory, from overhead camera?

Tags: c, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to build trajectory of moving camera which is seeing downwards. It works perfectly when camera is just translating, but fails when camera rotates. How to take into account of camera heading?

I am using feature matching which gives me where the specific patch is in my image and identifies the coordinates. I am tracking that patch and it give me trajectory of camera (if camera is not rotating.) But when camera rotates at a single place, it identifies the patch at the same place, and when camera starts moving it doesn't take into account of it.

For eg. if my camera is moving forward in north direction and camera is rotated to south and starts moving forward, my algorithm will not recognize it it builds trajectory just a straight line, instead of a right angle.
How to take into account of the camera rotation.

Comment: Hint: use more than a single patch. What about three patches?

Comment: It will take more resources and I am on a resource crunch here.

Answer (score 1):

> It works perfectly when camera is just translating, but fails when camera rotates. How to take into account of camera heading?

1. Direct approach (probably not possible)

Something must be responsible for the camera rotating. This something may know how much the camera rotates and may be able to tell you. I guess that in your case this information might not be readily available though.

2. Feature based image registration

A single feature is not sufficient to detect all affine transformations (translation, rotation, scaling, ..). You would need to take two features at least (for translation and rotation) or better three features (for full affine transformations) into account.

In case of two features and translation and rotation only, the center of the two features is the translation and the orientation of the connection of the two features is the rotation.

3. Frequency domain, intensity based image registration

Cross-correlation (via FFT) is fast in detecting translations, however, you can use this technique also for detecting rotation and scaling (see [An FFT-based technique for translation, rotation, and scale-invariant image registration](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/506761) or [Robust image registration using Log-Polar Transform](http://www-cs.engr.ccny.cuny.edu/~wolberg/pub/icip00.pdf))

4. Improved accuracy

Instead of comparing consecutive camera frames with features or intensity based techniques, compare all possible frame combinations within a certain time window (for example the time to move half a frame away), then find the single trajectory that fits all the transformations for all combinations. Computationally more expensive but more accurate.

5. Some words of caution

If the direct approach fails, you may be fooled by the image structures. In certain cases (uniform images, rotationally symmetric images, ...) it just won't work without an independent confirmation.

Comment: This helped a lot.
Regarding direct method. Suppose if I have heading information how to take it into account. 
I am getting coordinates of trajectory in x and y in pixels. Now suppose if I have heading information in North and East format, how can I incorporate it in my code?